# #if DEBUG executes when external debugger attached?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is `#if DEBUG` executed when the program is debugged after it has been released (for example by debugger tools like OllyDBG) or is it already nuked by the compiler on release build?

Means whatever I do with #if DEBUG is visible after the program has been created on release build?

Answer (score 1):

`#if DEBUG` is processed during compilation. The code inside is not compiled if the `DEBUG` symbol is not defined, so it cannot be executed in a release build.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx):

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, compiler directives like `#if DEBUG` are resolved at compile time, depending on the set symbols. In practice this means that the build configuration is taken into consideration. If `DEBUG` is not set during build, attaching a debugger later cannot make the removed part of the implementation magically reappear; the corresponding parts are indeed 'nuked' during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pre-processor directive, so the code within the `#if` is compiled only if `DEBUG` symbol exists.

Thus, you won't be able to debug a code that it's not part of compiled intermediate language code...

Answer (score 0):

`#if DEBUG` has nothing to do with Debugging but simply includes or excludes a part of source code in a build/assembly.

The standard Release Build settings do not define DEBUG so any code inside a `#if DEBUG` will not be part of a Release Build